# How to dynamic meta tag and meta description from database for different pages in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to show mete tag and meta description dynamic for all different pages from the database but i don't know how can i do that please help me thanks.

```
{
"id": 23,
"parent_id": 0,
"icon": "home",
"icon_type": "FontAwesome5",
"name": "Home",
"route": "home",
"is_seo": 1,
"is_content": 1,
"content_route": "content.home",
"seo_tags": "DEMO DEMO",
"seo_description": "The homepage for alahazrat.info",
"sort": 1,
"status": 1,
"created_at": "2019-05-15T15:52:54.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-10-27T14:58:05.000000Z"
}
```

**controller**

```
 public function index()
    {
        $data = [
            
             'webmenu_seo' => WebMenu::where('is_seo',1)->first(),
        ];
        return view('home',$data);
    }
```

**master.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> @yield('title')</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="{{url('')}}/assets/images/fav.png">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Markaz-E-AhleSunant Hyderabad | Official Website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="{{url('')}}/assets/images/ogimg.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="" />

    <meta name="description" content="@yield('description')">
```

**home.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title', 'Home')

@section('description','decription here' )

@section('top-styles')
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use yield too for it

#### master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> @yield('title')</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="{{url('')}}/assets/images/fav.png">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Markaz-E-AhleSunant Hyderabad | Official Website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="{{url('')}}/assets/images/ogimg.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="@yield('seo_description','put Default description will be show if this section dont declear')" />

    <meta name="description" content="@yield('description')">
```

#### home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title', 'Home')

@section('seo_description')
{{ $webmenu_seo['seo_description'] }}
@endsection


@section('description','decription here' )

@section('top-styles')
```